# Is outh 2.0 more secure than basic auth over an http connection?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, basic-authentication

I read in many places that basic auth is not secure over http connection because client's password can easily be derived from the encoded value. But if that is the case, then is oauth 2.0 secure over http? 
In oauth 2.0 after the browser receives the access token, it appends the token to all the request made to server. In that case if someone gets hold of the access token, although they cannot derive the password from it, they can still use this access token to make requests to server masquerading as the user. 
If this is not the case , then can anyone please explain where am I wrong and why is oauth 2.0 considered more secure than basic auth over http connection?

P.S: The scenario I have used in above example is related to client logging into an application using his username and password

Answer (score 3):

Using OAuth 2.0 over plain http is insecure and is prohibited by spec: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-5.3 which says:

> Always use TLS (https):  Clients MUST always use TLS [RFC5246]
> (https) or equivalent transport security when making requests with
> bearer tokens.  Failing to do so exposes the token to numerous
> attacks that could give attackers unintended access.

Then again, the reason that OAuth in general is considered more secure than basic authentication is because OAuth 2.0 tokens inherently have an expiry associated with them whereas basic authentication does not. So losing a token to an attacker would at least restrict the attacker in the time window that it can be used.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. So, if I am planning to implement basic security in my web application, using basic auth over https connection should also serve the purpose right?